# Usage of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid_Renderer_Checkbox

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, newsletter

I just stumbled upon `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid_Renderer_Checkbox` and am not able to tell where exactly this renderer is actually used.
Can anybody tell me? Or is it some relict that is still there but not used anymore (I am using 1.7.0.2)? Just curious.

In my opinion it would make sense to use it as a renderer in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid::_prepareColumns` but there is no reference. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this but I think it's a copy/paste issue.
There is this other renderer for the newsletter problems grid. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Problem_Grid_Renderer_Checkbox`. that one is actually used in  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Problem_Grid`.

```
 $this->addColumn('checkbox', array(
         'sortable'     => false,
        'filter'    => 'adminhtml/newsletter_problem_grid_filter_checkbox',
        'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/newsletter_problem_grid_renderer_checkbox',
        'width'     => '20px'
    ));
```

The one you are asking about is not used and it has never been used (at least from 1.1.1 'till now).
I think someone just created it because it cloned the `problems` grid.